# ARRAYFORMULA from Google Sheets not working in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have an ARRAYFORMULA with regular expression matching in Google Sheets that I need to convert to Excel.

The working Sheets formula is:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(regexmatch(E2:E,"Call"),100*(I2:I*D2:D),""))`

But I'm not having any luck debugging it in Excel.

The formula checks column E to see if the cell for row x contains the text "call". If it does, then it multiplies the value in the column(I) cell by the value in the column(D) cell.

**EDIT**

[image]

L2 has the formula:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",E2:E10)),100*D2:D10*I2:I10,"")`

Also tried this: `=IF(E2:E8="Call",100*L3D2:D8*I2:I8,"")`

Both return the spill error and I don't know how many rows I'll have so the formula wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: when you get a spill error - all that means is that you should only fill in the very first cell - Excel will figure out how many rows (or columns, depending on the formula) are required from the dimensions of the table you reference (if you are getting this then you either have something below or to the right that is blocking excel from returning the array in question)...

Comment: I have updated my soln with comment below - now includes a linked spreadsheet - I'm fairly confident that the solution I provided is working - but there is an application issue - so happy to work with you to resolve this - give the suggestions I have included below my solution (comment / response to your reply) a go -then we'll take it from there.  good luck! I'll watch this space to see how you get along (if you can advise whether the screenshots I included in my solution do not look like the correct solution, will take it back to the drawing board and resolve accordingly), Br, J ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fn1 - Regex equivalent** *(padding, case sensitive filter)*

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",B2:B8)),100*D2:D8*E2:E8,"")
```

[image: Regex equivalent: padding, case sensitive]

This provides for the following per the Regex function:

1. Case preservation (i.e. `"A" <> "a"` etc.)
2. Padding allowed (i.e. "12-Call", "Callxyz" etc. will match too)

***Revision***:
see [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9htZsgnmTlt0eH94o9w?e=UWFAv6) for sample file (which is clearly 'working' per screenshot[s] below - noting any 'spill' errors are due to something below the function that is getting in the way - only enter the function in a single cell - the other cells will automatically populate - this is an array function) - If you are not using Excel 365, then use this function, and include it in the table:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",B2)),100*C2*D2,"")
```

[image: Within Table]

Likely that you are using 365 Office compatible version of Excel though (because older versions did **not** have "SPILL!" feature - in which case you can simply enter the following funciton in a single cell and hit enter! ☺

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",B2:B7)),100*C2:C7*D2:D7,"")
```

[image: Array function]

The remainder of my solution (which is virtually identical to above, minus the table entry option) now resumes:

---

**Fn2 - Alternative** * *FYI (strict equality)**

Whilst the scope of this Q does not encompass variations - I provide 1 simple example for the sake of interest.  This differs from the function above by placing the additional restriction of 'strict equality' (i.e. no 'padding')...

```
=IF(B2:B8="Call",100*D2:D8*E2:E8,"")
```

[image: Strict equality]

---

**Final comments**

*RE: equivalence between Sheets and Microsoft Excel versions of this function..*

I believe the ranges `E2:E`, `I2:I` are dynamic (I may be mistaken), but if not, here are a couple of alternative ways to achieve the same in Excel:

```
=LET(x_, MAX(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(E:E)),--(E:E<>"")))-2, E2:OFFSET(E2,x_,0))
```

[image: Dynamic range - robust approach]

- This will take the dynamic range from E2 to the final non-blank cell in that column
- A common popular alternative is the simpler approach: `E2:offset(E2, counta(E2:E100) -1,0)`
- Whilst simpler, it is vulnerable to blank cells that fall within the data
- That said, the former (see screenshot) requires Office 365-compatible Excel

If dynamic ranges are important - you could also suing Tables in Excel) i.e. navigate to: *(File | Options | Formulas | 'Use Table Names in formulas if this was desired)*

[image: Dynamic ranges through table names]

Comment: This doesn't work. I need something like this: =IF(E2:E="Call",100*D2:D*I2:I,"") but I get a #NAME? error with that. "Call" will always just be Call, and the other columns will always be numbers. But I don't know the number of rows. Seems like there should be something simple like my google sheets solution. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Edited my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @reknirt - You can see the function does work in my screenshots).  I suspect your issue has something to do with the way that you have populated the function - you are only supposed to enter it in a single cell - not every single cell (which is why you are getting the '#SPILL!' error - I have updated my solution to include a onedrive link with sample excel workbook (I think you'll need to create a free OneDrive account to be able to access it) - but otherwise - see what happens if you clear all the cells below L1 in your lastest screenshot (just enter the fn in L1, press enter)?

Comment: Thanks fo much for your time and help -- very kind of you. The formula works great if I know the number of rows -- but I will not know this as its always changing -- so I need to use the =LET(x_, MAX(FILTER... formula. How do I pair that with IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Call",B2:B7)),100*C2:C7*D2:D7,"") ? Thanks so much.

Comment: V glad to hear! If you have it in the table then the dimensions will automatically update if you use the method I showed - i.e. include table names in formulas.  It'll seem unnatural at first because the names are unwieldy / cannot be edited as easily - but hey- if it does the trick, (the alternative is to have the table itself in 'spill/array' format - the range gets replaced with # sign so E2# would refer to the entire array from E2 to the bottom).  Otherwise, if you want to be overkill - use the funky fn I gave.  Accept/decline the solution for benefit of future users pls-ta,

Comment: I see! Thanks again for everything. Huge help. Very kind of you.

Comment: Ah- glad you came right in the end mate - np!